# Shiny switchInput: rendering differently in different computers

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a simple switchInput with the following code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
switchInput(inputId = "somevalue", label = "Custom <br> <b> ICD10 </b>", value = FALSE,
          onLabel = "<strong>ON</strong>", offLabel = "<strong>OFF</strong>", size = "small"))


server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Testing it in different computers however, produced different results. Even though the R version was the same and both used most up to date libraries.

Computer 1:

[image]

Computer 2:

[image]

It has cut off the top corner of both handles on computer 2. I tried playing around with 'labelWidth' instead of using < br> but the results remained the same. Any suggestions on how to fix this bug ?

Comment: I think the problem comes from which browser you are using. could you please list the different browsers you have tested on!

Comment: The shiny app opens through the inbuilt browser within R-Studio, which is what I have been using. I have now tried opening it with Google Chrome and Internet Explorer and the shown rendering issue does not appear on computer 1 irrespective of what browser is used.

Comment: do both computer have connection to the internet?

Comment: Yes, they are both connected.